# Not able to erase LLVM instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have following LLVM snippet.

```
invoke.cont22:                                    ; preds = %invoke.cont14
  %coerce.dive34 = getelementptr %"class.thrust::iterator_adaptor.33"* %coerce.dive33, i32 0, i32 0
  %8 = load i32** %coerce.dive34
  %coerce.dive39 = getelementptr %"class.thrust::iterator_adaptor.33"* %coerce.dive38, i32 0, i32 0
  %9 = load i32** %coerce.dive39
  %coerce.dive44 = getelementptr %"class.thrust::iterator_adaptor.33"* %coerce.dive43, i32 0, i32 0
  %10 = load i32** %coerce.dive44
  %coerce.dive45 = getelementptr %struct.my_functor* %agg.tmp29, i32 0, i32 0
  %11 = load i32* %coerce.dive45
  %call47 = invoke i32* @_ZN6thrust9transformINS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIiEEEES5_10my_functorEET0_T_S8_S7_T1_(i32* %8, i32* %9, i32* %10, i32 %11)
          to label %invoke.cont46 unwind label %lpad
```

From this I want to erase

```
%call47 = invoke i32* @_ZN6thrust9transformINS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIiEEEES5_10my_functorEET0_T_S8_S7_T1_(i32* %8, i32* %9, i32* %10, i32 %11)
```

But when I call eraseFromParent() on this instruction it is throwing following error:

> Basic Block in function 'main' does not have terminator!

How do I remove it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it is because your BasicBlock ends with `invoke` instruction, so it serves as BB's terminator. So when you remove it, your BB lose its terminator and that's an error, because every BasicBlock should end with terminator instruction.

As a solution, you can add `ret` instruction after deleting `invoke`.

Comment: Correct. Also, as a quick hack you can use the `unreacheable` instruction which is also a terminator.